# SQL server 2008 R2 BCP command export nvarchar data to excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, export-to-excel, bcp

I m using SQL Server 2008 R2 BCP command to export data from query to excel.

Now the problem is, while exporting to excel one of the column (CustomerName) is coming "????" .. i checkout the difference between other columns which are having exact value as in database table. The difference is datatype VARCHAR & NVARCHAR. Now i tried various options or switches provided by BCP command but still was not able to export the names correctly.

One of live example is "合肥公交集团" this is the original value in my database table & when extracting to excel i get "???????" some question marks.

I have used -N, -n, -w but failed to get desired result.

I also tried code_page but failed (maybe my syntax was wrong).

Please help....

Regards,
Avi

Eric tried this BCP command - 
c:\Avi>bcp "SELECT * from CMRQATEST..test" queryout "D:\Testing\nvarchartexttest\test.xls" -C 936 -S localhost -T -c

Result:

[image]

When Copying from SSMS, and pasting in excel sheet :[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try add `-C 936` in you BCP command, that's the code for Chinese Simplified (Windows ANSI 936)

Comment: Hi Eric, tried as u suggested by didn't work as i wanted... :(

Comment: Hi Eric, gone to this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , tried almost all chinese code_page , none of them worked for me... :(

Comment: Acutally, by look at your screenshot, it should work now. It just Excel didn't display it correctly. Do you have Language Settings as Chinese Simplified in Excel?

Comment: Yes Eric we have in Excel datatype as Special there we can define Locale but not working... I tried 1 more random test, and found that when i m running the query in SSMS and copy the data from result set and pasting in the Excel sheet i m getting exactly as SSMS showing..

Comment: Attached screen shots... its just a random R&D stuff as why BCP command act differently whereas Copying from same environment data is coming exactly same in excel... little confuse because we are trying to do same operations in both BCP and Coping manually .. taking data from SQL server and exporting to excel..